# Laravel 5 validation with array

Tags: angularjs, validation, post, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a problem with the Laravel 5 Validation, I post data with the Angular method $http.post. I have allready created a Request file called, CreateProjectRequest.

The posted data looks like this.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => 
        [title] => test
        [tasks] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [vat_id] => 1
                        [title] => 'test
                        [quantity] => 
                        [rate] => 
                        [costs] => 
                    )
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => 
        [title] => test2
        [tasks] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [vat_id] => 1
                        [title] => test
                        [quantity] => 
                        [rate] => 
                        [costs] => 
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I need to validate title and tasks, how can I reach that?

I tried a few things but the I get each time a error. For example title is required while title was filled in.

```
// Empty rules array
$rules = [];

foreach ($this->request->all() as $keyGroup => $request)
{
    $rules['title'] = 'required';

    // Loop throug tasks
    foreach ($request['tasks'] as $key => $task) 
    {
        $rules['quantity'] = 'required|numeric';
    }
 }
 return $rules;
```

Comment: where is your L5 validation code ?

Comment: @Creator How do you mean? I tried a few options but none of them work so I thought it's not needed.

Comment: what are those few things that you tried ? how did you define validator on post action method in l5 controller ?. when you say title was filled and it says error . it means there can be mismatch in title name which you are specifying in your validator .

Comment: @Creator i will edit my question

Comment: @Creator I have now edit my question, I call the request file inside of my controller like this: "CreateProjectRequest $request". But the response is always title is required.

Comment: Where have you called / created] the validator ? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#manually-creating-validators as specified here

Comment: @Creator I don't do it manually in the controller I called the Form Request Validation "CreateProjectRequest".